# Dropzone does not submit form and do proper ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone to upload images in my form and then send to my Django view in order to process. However, I have an issue. If I do not add any images the form is submitted correctly and Ajax will update my template properly. However, if I add an image, I can see the form is submitted however, it requires me to refresh the page. if I remove `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropagation` the form will then be submitted twice.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" data-url="{% url 'home:post-create' %}" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone post-create-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- my form foes here -->
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer col-12">
        <button type="submit" id="sub-etal" class="btn btn-primary"  style="border-radius: 20px; width: 100%;">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my Dropzone initialization:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready (function () {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone" , {
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            url: "/home/post/create/",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function () {
                var myDropzone = this;
                this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) { 
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();                     
                        myDropzone.processQueue();  
                    } else {                       
                        myDropzone.uploadFiles([]); //send empty 
                    }                                    
                });
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function () {
                });
                this.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
                });
                this.on("errormultiple", function (files, response) {
                });
                myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
                myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                });

            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

And in a separate js file I handle posting with **Ajax** using:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        //it seems this functions does not function at all and it doesnt get called after clicking on submit
        var SaveForm =  function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var form = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: form,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.form_is_valid){
                        $('#modal-post').modal('hide');
                        $('#_np2u').prepend(data.post);
                    } else {
                        $('#modal-post .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
                    }
                }
            })
            return false;
        }

    $('#modal-post').on("submit",".post-create-form",SaveForm)
    });
```

Also, my form is in a modal, so I need the modal to close and the Ajax to prepend the new post. as I said if I do not upload any image it works successfully but if I do I need to close the modal and refresh the page to work.

Thanks in advance!